# Node & forever wont start

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

ive installed node using:

```
sudo apt-get install node
```

Then afterwards:

```
sudo npm install forever --global
```

Now trying to run my server using

```
forever start server.js
```

Nothing happens no error nothing:

```
root@socialServer:/var/www/socialAPI# forever start server.js
root@socialServer:/var/www/socialAPI# node server.js 
root@socialServer:/var/www/socialAPI#
```

So nothing really happens :s

Can anyone tell me if im missing something or have done something wrong

im using ubuntu 14.04

Server.js:

```
    // BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var es = require('express-sequelize');
var multer = require('multer');
var Excel = require("exceljs");
var ex = require('xlsjs');
var stream = require('stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var async = require('async');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// =============================================================================

//Secure

app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});


var env = app.get('local') == 'development' ? 'dev' : app.get('env');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8092;

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// db config
var env = "local";
var config = require('./database.json')[env];
var password = config.password ? config.password : null;

// initialize database connection
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        port: config.port,
        host: config.server,
        logging: console.log,
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        }
    }
);

var user = {};

var done = {is_complete: false};

app.use(multer({
    dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        //Redirects request to path
    }
}));

var auth = require('./auth.js')(express, sequelize, router);

app.all('/api/*', [require('./middlewares/validateRequest')]);

app.use('/', router);
app.use(auth);


//Init models
var user_model = require('./social_models/user/user_model')(express, sequelize, router, user, async);

var family_model = require('./social_models/user/Family')(express, sequelize, router, user, async);

var post_model = require('./social_models/post/Post')(express, sequelize, router, user, async);

app.use(user_model);
app.use(family_model);
app.use(post_model);

// If no route is matched by now, it must be a 404
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: `node server.js` also finishes immediately, right? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @thefourtheye the node server.js should start my server and run it in console

Comment: Can we see the server.js code? Did you forget to listen on a port?

Comment: @lxe it works on my local machine but sure il post the server code to my question

Comment: I don't think with forever running you nodejs app you will see anything at the command line...it is designed to run in the background...run `top` to see what is running on the server and look for your app.

Comment: @DrCord When forever starts it gives me a message normally and i can see on my domain that it is not running!

Comment: yeah, sorry, I forgot it does normally give a startup message...

Comment: as @thefourtheye asked - what happens if you try and run your code without forever? does it end immediately also?

Comment: @DrCord Yeah well it doesnt give me any messages!

Comment: So if it doesn't output anything and exits immediately without forever, then why would it be any different with forever? It may be useful that it doesn't show the forever message...but first you need to make your code work without forever...

Comment: Are you running on a specific port or the default you have, `8092`? Because, if it's under `1024` you'll need to run node as root on most servers. Granted, you should see an error if that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some others have said, the whole point of forever is to daemonize your node app and let it run in the background.

If you check `forever list` or `top`, you will most likely see all the instances you have started. `forever -h` will tell you all the different commands and options you can use to start and stop processes.

I would however suggest looking into using node's native [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster). I haven't use forever for a long time, but it used to be less than ideal in a production environment, and although still marked as unstable in the official docs, `cluster` has proven reliable and lightweight in my experience so far.